Win11Pro23H2 OEM custom The product key entered does not match any of the windows images available for installation. Enter a different product key
I've tried to create a custom Win11 Pro Image with preinstalled apps using this article:
https://woshub.com/create-custom-windows-image-preinstalled-apps/#comment-11977
Tried to install the image, get to the point I need to enter license key and after entering right key (from the label on the bottom of the laptop) I get an error message saying: "The product key entered does not match any of the windows images available for installation. Enter a different product key"
I'm using Win11 Pro OEM 23H2 version

Tried to create PID.txt file with: [PID] Value=xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx, with license key itself - doesn't work.

Tried to create ei.cfg file and write in it: [Channel] Retail
[VL] 0 - doesn't work.



Please post the answer file in a code box, as an OEM key should be saved within the firmware and not need to be entered - only the generic key would be required under the windowsPE configuration pass, not specialize. The answer file has two spots for product keys that should both be used AFAIK - one is for the windowsPE configuration pass, which can be a generic key to install Windows, whereas the other is under the specialize configuration pass and this is the activation key. Please refer to Step 5 under Configuring a ZTI.

(Cont'd...) If the WIM will only be used on the machine it's been created on, link posted is for a reference image to be deployed on multiple machines, which must be generalized prior to imaging. All that's needed to create a WIM for the machine its been created on is to customize Windows how you want it, capture a WIM, append new images to that WIM overtime (every 4 - 6mo), then when wanting to reinstall Windows on the same machine, skip the installer, format the OS partition, and apply the WIM. See Steps 1-2 (top) & 1-6 (bottom) in this answer
